# Why Python script works differently when using ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook which will call a shell script on a remote server, the shell script will call another python script, which will do something, when I run the ansible playbook, the script is not working, but when I ssh to the server and run the same command manually, it worked. I've done some debugging, seems when calling the python script, if I delete all the import statements from the python script, it works from ansible, but I don't understand why it works when I ssh to the server and would like to have some suggestion on how to resolve this issue.

the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import argparse
import logging
import subprocess
import time
import imp

def main():
    f = open('/afile', 'w')
    f.write('a test line')
    f.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

those imports are not using here, it will be used in my real script, here I just write a line into a file for debugging.

The ansible playbooks are just simply like:

```
---
- hosts: servers

tasks:
  - name: trigger the script
    shell: /start.sh
```

The start.sh then simply invoke the python script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/start.py
```

Comment: What is minimal setting for `sh`/`python` script ? Your script is okay but maybe got `permission` error.  You can't write `root_dir` with python if user not `sudoers` or directory is `read only`. Try open file under `/tmp` you will be see all will be work. Another point is `chmod a+x start.py` than `./start.py` work directly.

Comment: Most likely you are setting `PYTHONPATH` in rc-files that are sourced only for interactive, login shells. Add the value to the `shell` task and check.

Comment: @dsgdfg, I don't think it's about permission of the script, as I said, when I delete all the import statements from the python script, it works even from ansible, so I guess the permission is ok.

Comment: @techraf, do you mean the PYTHONPATH on the remote machine or ansible machine? I can ensure that on the remote machine, I didn't set anything related to PYTHONPATH in rc files, but I do have some settings on ansible machine, where I run the playbook, not sure which python envrionment ansible use. also I found out I only need to remove the first three import statements to make it work even from ansible. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Remote. I did not mean you set the variable manually, a package manager might set it. The easiest thing you can do is to check. It takes less keystrokes than the above comment.

Comment: @techraf. I checked all the rc files I can think of, and no related thing, but thanks for your direct, I follow this lead, and finally found the reason, I will put an answer. thanks very much.

Comment: I did not ask you to check files, I asked you tu check the environment variable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, it's my bad, I didn't put all the scripts here, seems that there is another script which has things like

```
#!/bin/sh
/start & >> stdout.log
```

this caused the problem, I guess the first three modules imported have things related to standard io, so the solution is using nohup.

again, very sorry for the incomplete question.